# SQL LIKE not returning correct result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-like

I have a Person table with LastName and FirstName.

Consider the following record where

> FirstName == 'Pete' and LastName == 'Aaaa'

When I run the following select statements:

```
select * from Person where FirstName='Pete' and LastName like 'a%' -- 0 record returned
select * from Person where FirstName='Pete' and LastName like 'aa%' -- 1 record returned
select * from Person where FirstName='Pete' and LastName like 'aaa%' -- 0 record returned
select * from Person where FirstName='Pete' and LastName like 'aaaa%' -- 1 record returned
```

When I run this in SQL Fiddle - 1 record is returned for every select as it should [SQL Fiddle query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e603/2)

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Though I don't see why it should affect things like you describe, are you doing case insensitive comparisons?

Comment: could you provide your Person table schema? There might be collation problem

Comment: What is the column datatype? What is the result of `SELECT CAST(LastName AS VARBINARY(100))` for that row? Is this the exact query you are running or have you altered it for the purposes of the question?

Comment: My experience says that you are most likely doing something wrong. Maybe the `like` clause is corrupted (e.g. with a laeading space, or space-sensitivity has been activated between the calls, or the record has been changed by some other code between the calls (like the setup/teardown code of your test case).

Comment: I suspected there was some collation problem.. my DB has `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS`. I altered to `SQL_Latin_General_CP1_CI_AS` recreated the table and run queries again. Return results are ok..

Comment: you can use another collation without recreating table, see an answer

Comment: @camillajac - Ah `aa` in Danish/Norwegian is treated specially as `Å`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
select * from Person where FirstName='Pete' and LastName collate Latin1_General_CI_AS like 'a%'
select * from Person where FirstName='Pete' and LastName collate Latin1_General_CI_AS like 'aa%'
select * from Person where FirstName='Pete' and LastName collate Latin1_General_CI_AS like 'aaa%'
select * from Person where FirstName='Pete' and LastName collate Latin1_General_CI_AS like 'aaaa%'
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I have to find out how to do this in Linq; as Linq doesn't support collation (?)